# Change devise model configuration on a created model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rails 3.2.3
Ruby 1.9.3
Devise: 2.1.2

I created with anteriority a devise model called Users.

Then, some time passed and I want to change the regexp format of the email. I thought that changing the devise.rb initializer would do it, but nope.

So, how can I achieve this task?, please help.I wouldn't want to redo the devise model...

Comment: Did you restart Rails server after editing intializers/devise.rb?

Comment: When you say "I created with anteriority a devise model" does this mean "In the past, I created a devise model"? Did you change the name of the model that Devise was using as a resource? (For example changing User to Account)?  Or did you just want to change the content of the emails that Devise sends?  How does regexp come into this?

Answer (score 0):

The setting in *initializers/devise.rb*:

```
config.email_regexp
```

should be what you're looking to do. One reason you may not be seeing the intended result is because you didn't restart the web server.

If that doesn't help, please provide more details on what exactly you're changing the regexp to, and what you're seeing that tells you it's not being used.

Keep in mind, that you may also have an email validator in the User model, such as this:

```
validates :email, :format => { :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create }
```

If that's the case, it may be interfering with the devise config setting.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all. The problem was Spork. I was testing my app, but I never restarted the spork.... Thanks to all, really